# CustomTableCell Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I have a tableview called `AdminOrderViewController` and it has customcell called `StepperProgressCell`.

This customcell has a custom UIView called `AYStepperView`. There is a button in this UIView and I implemented a delegate on it, whenever it gets clicked and I want to this delegate `clicked` method to be called on `AdminOrderViewController`.

However, I do not know how to add cell.delegate??

**AdminOrderViewController.m**

```
@interface AdminOrderViewController : UIViewController <AYStepperViewDelegate>

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StepperProgressCell";
        StepperProgressTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[StepperProgressTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        //cell.stepperView.delegate= ???
        return cell;
}

- (void)clicked
{
 // is not getting called?
}
```

**StepperProgressTableViewCell.m**

```
@interface StepperProgressTableViewCell ()

@property (nonatomic) AYStepperView *stepperView;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger currentIndex;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger currentStep;
@property (nonatomic) UIView *containerView;

@end

@implementation StepperProgressTableViewCell
@synthesize stepperView;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setUpViews];
}

- (void)setUpViews {

    self.stepperView = [[AYStepperView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, kFormStepperViewHeight) titles:@[@"Processing",@"Ready",@"Delivered", nil)]];
    [self addSubview:self.stepperView];
}
```

**AYStepperView.m**

```
@protocol AYStepperViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)clicked;

@end

- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
   [stepperDelegate clicked];
}
```

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: cell.stepperView.delegate= self in your cellForRow just where you have it commented

Comment: cell does not access stepperView ??

Comment: what you mean, please explain yourself, if your stepperView is property of your cell you can do this without any problems, and your steeperView have a id<AYStepperViewDelegate > delegate

Comment: please check update.

Comment: can you post your `StepperProgressTableViewCell.h`

Comment: can you show your `StepperProgressTableViewCell.h`

Comment: @hotspring Your steeperVIew must be a property of your  StepperProgressTableViewCell to be accessed as public property

Comment: please check update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need declare your stteperView as property in your cell.h, your property is declared in the .m and is private, you need to declare in your .h

## StepperProgressTableViewCell.h

```
@interface StepperProgressTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic) AYStepperView *stepperView;

@end
```

After that you can `cell.stepperView.delegate= self` in your cellForRow

Hope this helps

Comment: any idea on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558996/collection-view-cell-is-square-but-image-is-rectangle

Answer (score 1):

hide the stepper property in your `StepperProgressTableViewCell.m`

```
 @interface StepperProgressTableViewCell ()

//@property (nonatomic) AYStepperView *stepperView;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger currentIndex;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger currentStep;
@property (nonatomic) UIView *containerView;

@end
```

Move the following property in your `StepperProgressTableViewCell.h` and check

```
@property (nonatomic) AYStepperView *stepperView
```

then set your delegate to stepperView;

```
cell.stepperView.delegate = self
```

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, Any idea on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499259/pass-cell-section-to-customtablecell?noredirect=1#comment77959329_45499259