# Pass cell.section to CustomTableCell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a tableview called `AdminOrderViewController` and it has customcell called `StepperProgressCell`.

This customcell has a custom UIView called `AYStepperView`. There is a button in this UIView and I implemented a delegate on it, whenever it gets clicked and I `clicked` method is getting called on `AdminOrderViewController`.

However, I could not able to figure out how to pass clicked header `cell.section` to `AYStepperView` ??

**AdminOrderViewController.m**

```
@interface AdminOrderViewController : UIViewController <AYStepperViewDelegate>

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StepperProgressCell";
        StepperProgressTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[StepperProgressTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.stepperView.delegate= self;
        return cell;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    AdminHeaderFooterView *sectionHeaderView = [self.adminTableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];

    if (sectionHeaderView == nil)
    {
        sectionHeaderView = [[AdminHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:SectionHeaderViewIdentifier];
    }

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectHeaderAction:)];
    [sectionHeaderView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    return sectionHeaderView;
}

-(void) selectHeaderAction :(UITapGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer
{
  AdminHeaderFooterView* cell = (AdminHeaderFooterView*)gestureRecognizer.view;
   [self toggleSection:cell withSection: cell.section];
   // how to pass clicked section to AYStepperView??
}

-(void)clicked :(NSUInteger) currentSection
{
    NSLog(@"Stepper clicked %lu", currentSection);
}
```

**StepperProgressTableViewCell.m**

```
@implementation StepperProgressTableViewCell
@synthesize stepperView;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setUpViews];
}

- (void)setUpViews {

    self.stepperView = [[AYStepperView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 , [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, kFormStepperViewHeight) titles:@[@"Processing",@"Ready",@"Delivered", nil)]];
    [self addSubview:self.stepperView];
}
```

**AYStepperView.h**

```
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger currentSection;
```

**AYStepperView.m**

```
@protocol AYStepperViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)clicked :(NSUInteger) currentSection;

@end

- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
   [stepperDelegate clicked : currentSection];
}
```

Comment: you want to call clicked when header is clicked ?

Comment: when user click on the header, then I want to pass clicked section to `AYStepperView`, header click method is already implemented with `tapGesture`. But I do not know how to pass `section number` to `AYStepperView` to assign `currentSection`.. `currentSection` is required for delegate method.

Comment: You would normally have the delegate receive the cell instance itself, then the view controller can use `indexPathForCell` to get the index path for that cell; `[stepperDelegate clicked: self];`

Comment: @Paulw11, interesting.. Could you please elaborate as an answer please?

Comment: where you called the buttonPressed method

Comment: There is a button inside the `AYStepperView`. Whenever this button is clicked, then `buttonPressed` event is getting fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell should not need to know which row or section it is in; Your table view controller can find this easily, given a reference to the cell.

Your view controller should not set itself as the delegate of the stepper view.  It should be a delegate of the cell.  The cell should be the delegate of the stepper view.  This is a bit more complicated but it maintains better separation of concerns and makes the whole thing cleaner.

**AYStepperView.h**

```
@protocol AYStepperViewDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)clicked;

@end
```

**AYStepperView.m**

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
   [stepperDelegate clicked];
}
```

**StepperProgressTableViewCell.h**

```
@protocol StepperProgressTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- stepperChanged: (StepperProgressTableViewCell) cell;
```

**StepperProgressTableViewCell.m**

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    self.stepperView.delegate= self;
}

- (void)clicked {
   [self.delegate stepperChanged: self];
}
```

**AdminOrderViewController.m**

```
@interface AdminOrderViewController : UIViewController <StepperProgressTableViewCellDelegate>

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StepperProgressCell";
        StepperProgressTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[StepperProgressTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.delegate= self;
        return cell;
}

-(void)stepperChanged:(StepperProgressTableViewCell)cell {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    //  Now do something with indexPath.section
}
```

Comment: `@interface StepperProgressTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <AYStepperViewDelegate>` is needed?

Comment: Yes.  The cell is now the stepper delegate

Comment: Could you please check my update section, there is an issue which I could not able to make it work.

Comment: Can you clarify "not working"?  Have you set breakpoints to see which part of the code is being executed?

Comment: `- (void)clicked` is not getting called inside `StepperProgressTableViewCell.m`, am I missing anything. I have put what I have in the update section in my question.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your button handler code in `AYStepperView.m` - Is the `stepperDelegate` property set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151025/discussion-between-paulw11-and-hotspring).

Answer (score 0):

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set section to stepper view

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StepperProgressCell";
        StepperProgressTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[StepperProgressTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.stepperView.delegate= self;
        cell.stepperView.currentSection = indexPath.section;//set section value
        return cell;
}
```

Comment: what is the log in `NSLog(@"Stepper clicked %lu", currentSection);` ?

Comment: dont set in here`cell.stepperView.currentSection = indexPath.section;//set section value` set in inside the viewforheadersection
`

Comment: seems like the `stepperView` is in `StepperProgressTableViewCell` and header is  another view `AdminHeaderFooterView`

Comment: Exactly, those are in different classess.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, `cell` in the `viewHeaderSection`?

Comment: @hotspring do you have more than one section returning from `numberOfSections` method?

Comment: Yes I do have multiple headerSections.