# UICollectionViewCell is square, but image is rectangle

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using UICollectionView where cell's are almost square, but original image is rectangle. Therefore, when I display image as follows, it is getting cut.

Is there a way to handle this issue?

I am currently working on Objective-C but I am to see Swift solution as well.

cell.productImage content mode is `Aspect Fill`

```
cell.productImage.image = [cell.productImage.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
```

[image]

Comment: What does the posted code have to do with your issue? What is your issue exactly? How should the images be shown?

Comment: I am just showing related code where collectionview image are being handled/displayed. I have rectangle images but my collection view image is square; therefore, image is getting cut.

Comment: It makes no sense to set this image's rendering mode to "template", that's why I ask.

Comment: `cell.productImage` content mode is `Aspect Fill`

Comment: And what does that have to do with the rendering mode code in your question? Content mode and rendering mode have nothing to do with each other, hence the confusion by your question. Why did you use "Aspect Fill" for the content mode if that isn't what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Please add this line to your code.

```
cell.productImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```